# Does the French Defense have any variation similar to the King's Indian Defense opening

Tags: french-defense

I recently won with the French Defense. Does Nh3 early on have any benefits?

```
[Fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2016.08.10"]
[White "1itsamovie"]
[Black "anandsadasivam"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "675"]
[BlackElo "670"]
[TimeControl "10|0"]
[Termination "anandsadasivam won by checkmate"]

1.e4 e6 2.Nh3 d5 3.d3 dxe4 4.dxe4 Nd7 5.Qf3 Ngf6 6.e5 Nxe5 7.Qg3 Bd6 8.f4 Nc6 9.Na3 Ne4 10.Qxg7 Qh4+
 11.Kd1 Rf8 12.g3 Qh5+ 13.Ke1 Qf3 14.Rg1 Bc5 15.Rg2 Nd4 16.c3 Nf5 17.Qe5 c6 18.g4 Ne3 19.Nf2 Nxg2+ 20.Bxg2 Qxf2+
 21.Kd1 Qg1+ 22.Kc2 Qxg2+ 23.Kb1 Nd2+ 24.Bxd2 Qxd2 25.b4 Be3 26.Nc2 Qc1# 0-1
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The French is a defense against e4, the King's Indian is a defense against d4, and can be used against c4 & Nf3 as well. There really isn't anything they share. Better would be comparing the French to some lines of the QGD.

Comment: Wiki says in its diagram 1. e4 e6 itself a French Defense, but first three moves in draughts board decides the variation. And when it comes to King's Indian Defense I find many variation. In French its comparatively less is so. If not please let us know, how and all it can be the variation. Particularly this one.

Comment: Yes, 1. e4 e6 is a French defense. Not every opening has a lot of variations, but the French does have several, many of which are more determined by white's moves than blacks.

Comment: The question title and the actual question are completely different. It literally does not make any sense whatsoever. Please consider rephrasing the question completely, because right now, I cannot see how anyone besides OP could possibly understand this.

Comment: I didn't understand what's that op; Set your `flow free` please!

Answer (score 1):

Other than surprise value (dubious value) and keep players out of book, it's a pretty lousy move and goes against basic development principles.

Play good normal moves to guarantee at least equal play. So if you can manage some sort of KID formation it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The move Nh3 is unusual to say the least. It might have some value later in the game by supporting a White pawn on f4. But when White played it on his second move, there was no such pawn on f4. So it was a "wasted" move that gave you an extra move, and the initiative. A few more bad moves (with the queen and the sacrifice of the e pawn) gave you the game.